# List of Personalization Rules Conditions and What it Triggers

Tags: presentation, personalization, powershell

Is there a way in Sitecore to get a list personalization with it rules conditions and what triggers it? Prefer to use PowerShell if it can be done that way or an OOB method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the following script:

`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Reporting/Content Reports/Reports/Content Audit/Items with personalized renderings`

[image: Sample Report]

Through the Sitecore API you can extract more details about the rules.

Comment: Yeah I saw that example. Not really what I need, but could be a starting point.